# C++ Encoding Numbers

Tags: c++, encoding

I am currently working on sending data to a receiving party based on mod96 encoding scheme. Following is the request structure to be sent from my side:

```
Field                          Size          Type
1. Message Type                2             "TT"
2. Firm                        2             Mod-96
3. Identifier Id               1             Alpha String
4. Start Sequence              3             Mod-96
5. End Sequence                3             Mod-96
```

My doubt is that the sequence number can be greater than 3 bytes. Suppose I have to send numbers 123 and 123456 as start and end sequence numbers, how to encode it in mod 96 format . Have dropped the query to the receiving party, but they are yet to answer it. Can somebody please throw some light on how to go about encoding the numbers in mod 96 format.

Comment: I would say they would have to specifically explain how they want it to be encoded, I don't think "modulo 96" is any generally used format. 96^3 would be 884736 so numbers under that should be encodable at least.

Comment: It is using the printable range of the ASCII set.  32-127 has 96 characters.   You will have to offset the value by 32 to get it within the printable range and remove the offset to reconstitute the number

Comment: can u please provide an example...i am new to this!!

Comment: 1) what do you mean by size?
2) expected types to be encoded
3) expected values for fields/ expected range of values..
4) You know we can't invent any encoding as long as you don't tell EXACTLY wich data you need to encode (and by exactly I mean showing a C++ program that shows possible values/min-max values/ and variable types (you know we may have to consider 2-complement, IEEE floating point arithmtetic etc.) For example it makes no sense to me encoding only part of the data with Mod96, Mod96 is required if you want data in a printable utf8 (7 bit limited) string.

Comment: according to the receiving party size is the size in bytes expected.

Comment: @chetan how do we know how to help you If you don't tell us all details?
Do you need to encode 3 characters and transmit a 3 bytes number, or do you need to encode a 3 bytes number and transmit it as 3 characters?

Comment: We need to encode numbers and send them as characters.So how do we encode a number say 123456 and transmit as characters?

Comment: you just have to use the "decode" function I provided in my answer. Usage example: `char a,b,c; decode(&a,&b,&c, 123456); // now you can send the 3 characters`
I think you can accept the answer now :) (just rename the function to what you think is better, I keept old name for clarity)

Answer (score 2):

Provided there's a lot of missing detail on what you really need, here's how works Mod-96 econding:

You just use printable characters as if they were digits of a number:

- when you encode in base `10` you know that 123 is `10^2*1 + 10^1*2 + 10^0*3`
- (oh and note that you arbitrary choose that `1`'s value is really one: `value('1') = 1`
- when you encode in base `96` you know that 123 is

  `96^2*value('1')+ 96^2*value('2')+96^0*value('3')`
- since `'1'` is the ASCII character #49 then `value('1') = 49-32 = 17`

Encoding 3 printable characters into a number

```
unsigned int encode(char a, char b, char c){
    return (a-32)*96*96 + (b-32)*96 + (c-32);
}
```

Encoding 2 printable characters into a number

```
unsigned int encode(char a, char b){
    return (b-32)*96 + (c-32);
}
```

Decoding a number into 2 printable characters

```
void decode( char* a, char*b, unsigned int k){
    * b = k % 96 +32;
    * a = k / 96 +32;
}
```

Decoding a number into 3 printable characters

```
void decode( char* a, char*b, char*c, unsigned int k){
    * c = k % 96 +32;
    k/= 96;
    * b = k % 96 +32;
    * a = k/96 +32;
}
```

You also of course need to check that characters are printable (between 32 and 127 included) and that numbers you are going to decode are less than 9216 (for 2 characters encoded) and 884736(for 3 characters encoded).

You know the final size would be 6 bytes:

- Size 2 `=>`  max of 9215 `=>` need 14 bits storage (values up to 16383 unused)
- Size 3 `=>`  max of 884735 `=>` need 17 bits storage (values up to 131071 unused)

Your packet needs 14+17+17 bits of memory (wich is 48 => exactly 6 bytes)  bits storage just for Mod-96 stuff.

**Observation:**

- Instead of 3 fields of sizes(2+3+3) we could have used one field of size(8) `=>` we would finally use 47 bits ( but is still rounded up to 6 bytes)
- If you still store each encoded number into a integer number of bytes you would use the same amount of memory (14 bits fits into 2 bytes, 17 bits fits into 3 bytes) used by storing chars directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dario... That was really helpful . Just one more doubt , according to the document I have received from the receiving party, they mentioned the sequence number to be of 3 bytes but in mod 96 format. The maximum value for that can be 884735. Now suppose i want to send a length of 123456 in mod 96 format that will be more than 3 bytes. That is confusing me??

Comment: You not giving me ENOUGH INFO to answer:
what means "Start Sequence"?
The first 3 characters of a ASCII text string and they wanted to pack them in 3 bytes integer(pretty senseless unless that's a error detection or a sort of "preivew)
Or it is a "index" that tells at wich points something ends and so it is a number they just encoded to printable ascii because transmission layer have only 7 bits and they want to use unused values to detect transmission errors?

Comment: You know, when you encoding something you have to be clear:
1) the data you really want at code level ( be it a text string, a boolean flag or a number)
2) how that data is laid out when transmitted over a cable.
You still not told to me what each Fields represent at code level. So I cannot know if you need to use "decode" or "encode" on the data you are transmitting (and note that I pointed out that accidentally the size is the same, so I cannot figure it out by looking at sizes. It is also silly to me encoding something without saving space ^^). Do such company use a standard? wich rfc?